$\mathscr{F}[f(\mathbf{r}]$ Converge to different values ​in k = 0， So does the integral (Fourier) result depend on the order of integration?
I now have a 3D function $f(\mathbf{r})$, and its fourier variations $\mathscr{F}[f](\mathbf{k})$
$$
F(\mathbf{k}) = \mathscr{F}[f](\mathbf{k}) \tag{1}
$$
Assume that there are convergences to different values ​​when $\mathbf{k} \to 0$:
$$
\lim\limits_{k_3 \to 0} \lim\limits_{k_1, k_2 \to 0} F[\mathbf{k}] \ne \lim\limits_{|\mathbf{k}| \to 0} F[\mathbf{k}] \tag{2}
$$
So when we perform Fourier transform on $f{\mathbf{r}}$, will changing the order of integration also result in different $F[\mathbf{k}]$? For example：
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx e^{ik_1x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy e^{ik_2y}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz e^{ik_3z} f(x,y,z) \\
\ne \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz e^{ik_3z} \int_{0}^{\infty}du \int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta f(u,\theta,z) \tag{3}
$$
When I was trying to deduce a function, I found an inequality. Is it reasonable that the Fourier transform results of the last two methods are not equal?

I use the function $f(\mathbf{r}) = \dfrac{erf(t\mathbf{r})}{\mathbf{r}}$， erf is the Gauss error function, the integral of this function on (infty, \infty) is divergent
